# JavaScript validation repeating the first error fix

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a form in my project with native JS

I am creating a function for every input validation

I created the first function to validate the user No. and it worked well

but when I created the user name validation function and tested it it shows the user No. error two times, and I tried to enter the No. and not enter the name and no errors displayed

Can anyone help me please?

this my code

```
$('#addUserBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let valid = false;
    let errors = [];

    if (validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        errors.push(validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()));
        console.log(errors);
    }

    if (validateName($('#userNameInput').val()) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        errors.push(validateName($('#userNameInput').val()));
        console.log(errors);
    }

    if (errors.length == 0) {
        valid = true;
    }

    if (valid == true) {
        let user = {
            no: $('#userNoInput').val(),
            name: $('#userNameInput').val(),
            email: $('#userEmailInput').val(),
            tel: $('#userTelInput').val(),
            dob: $('#userDobInput').val(),
            rmk: $('#userRmkInput').val(),
        }

        usersContainer.push(user);

        localStorage.setItem('myUsers', JSON.stringify(usersContainer));
        displayUsers();
        //clearForm();
    } else {
        let messages = Object.values(errors);
        let errorsMarkup = ""

        for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            errorsMarkup += `${messages[i]}`;
        }
        console.log(errorsMarkup);

        errorsMarkup = errorsMarkup.replace(/\./g, '<br>');

        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'خطأ...',
            confirmButtonText: 'حسناً',
            html: errorsMarkup
        });
    }
});

function validateNo(input) {
    if (input == '') {
        let error = "You must enter User No.";

        return error;
    }

    let reg = /^\d+$/;
    if (reg.test(input) == false) {
        let error = "Not valid User No.";

        return error;
    }

    return true;
}

function validateName(input) {
    if (input == '') {
        let error = "You must enter User Name.";

        return error;
    }

    let reg = /^[a-z\s]{0,255}$/i;
    if (reg.test(input) == false) {
        let error = "Not valid User Name.";

        return error;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your validation of the name field, you're calling validateNo instead of validateName in the else.

```
if (validateName($('#userNameInput').val()) == true) {
    return true;
} else {
    errors.push(validateNo($('#userNameInput').val()));
    console.log(errors);
};
```

Additionally, you're returning from your function early. This means that if there is no validation error for validateNo it will return true and not validateName.

```
if (validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        errors.push(validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()));
        console.log(errors);
    }

    if (validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()) == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            errors.push(validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()));
            console.log(errors);
        }
    
        if (validateName($('#userNameInput').val()) == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            errors.push(validateName($('#userNameInput').val()));
            console.log(errors);
        }
```

I would suggest changing your code to something like:

```
if (validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()) == true) {
errors.push(validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()));
console.log(errors);
}

if (validateName($('#userNameInput').val()) == true) {
errors.push(validateName($('#userNameInput').val()));
console.log(errors);
}
```

Comment: @OmarAmr I've edited my answer to be more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending your function if the `userNoInput` input is validated because of the `return true` in the `if` block.

```
if (validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()) == true) {
    return true; // This ends the function early, you want the function to keep going to validate the other fields
} else {
    errors.push(validateNo($('#userNoInput').val()));
    console.log(errors);
}
```

You need to remove the `return true`, just check if the individual validation functions return `false`, and keep going until all checks are done.

Then after the individual validations, check if the `errors` array is empty. If it is empty, it means there are no errors.

Comment: ty, I edited my code as you said but it's now not storing any errors in the the array because the validation functions returns the error message not returns boolean